# How to make loading animation in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I want to make animation with 3 `UIView`. The main problem is I can't start animation once it's stopped by removing animation from `layer`.

**Here is the code:**

```
class HTAnimatedTypingView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view3: UIView!

    func startAnimation(){

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {

        self.view1.frame.origin.y = 0

       }, completion: nil)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.5, options: .repeat, animations: {

               self.view2.frame.origin.y = 0

              }, completion: nil)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 1.0, options: .repeat, animations: {

                     self.view3.frame.origin.y = 0

                    }, completion: nil)

    }

    func stopAnimations(){

        self.view1.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.view2.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.view3.layer.removeAllAnimations()

    }
}
```

**Output of Above Code:**

[image]

**Expected Animation:**

[image]

How can make it work with start animation & stop animation functionality? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to use a `Timer`. Keep an instance of `Timer` in your class. When `startAnimation` is called, schedule it. When `stopAnimation` is called, `invalidate` it. (This means that the currently ongoing animation will be completed before the animation actually stops, which IMO makes it a nice non-abrupt stop).

On each tick of the timer, animate the dots *once*. Note that the animation you apply on each dot should have the *same* duration, as in the expected output, they all bounce at the same rate, just at different instants in time.

Some illustrative code:

```
// startAnimation
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: timerInterval, repeats: true) { _ in
    self.animateDotsOnce()
}

// stopAnimation
timer.invalidate()

// animateDotsOnce
UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, delay: 0, animations: {

    self.view1.frame.origin.y = animateHeight

}, completion: {
    _ in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
        self.view1.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
})

// plus the other two views, with different delays...
```

I'll leave it to you to find a suitable `animateHeight`, `timerInterval`, `animationDuration` and delays for each view.

Comment: Thank you!, Works good!; I set 0.2, 0.4 delay to view2, view3 and timer interval is 0.5(animation duration)+delays = 1.1; This works what I expected!

Comment: I would definitely not recommend using Timers for such a task while it can all be done very easily and in a more performant way via the dedicated API: UIView.animateKeyframes.

Comment: @AlexLinares Yeah, you're right... I'm not familiar with `animateKeyframes`...

Answer (score 6):

Since you need to add some pause in between each sequence of animations, I would personally do it using **key frames** as it gives you some flexibility:

```
class AnimationViewController: UIViewController {

    private let stackView: UIStackView = {
        $0.distribution = .fill
        $0.axis = .horizontal
        $0.alignment = .center
        $0.spacing = 10
        return $0
    }(UIStackView())

    private let circleA = UIView()
    private let circleB = UIView()
    private let circleC = UIView()
    private lazy var circles = [circleA, circleB, circleC]

    func animate() {
        let jumpDuration: Double = 0.30
        let delayDuration: Double = 1.25
        let totalDuration: Double = delayDuration + jumpDuration*2

        let jumpRelativeDuration: Double = jumpDuration / totalDuration
        let jumpRelativeTime: Double = delayDuration / totalDuration
        let fallRelativeTime: Double = (delayDuration + jumpDuration) / totalDuration

        for (index, circle) in circles.enumerated() {
            let delay = jumpDuration*2 * TimeInterval(index) / TimeInterval(circles.count)
            UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: totalDuration, delay: delay, options: [.repeat], animations: {
                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: jumpRelativeTime, relativeDuration: jumpRelativeDuration) {
                    circle.frame.origin.y -= 30
                }
                UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: fallRelativeTime, relativeDuration: jumpRelativeDuration) {
                    circle.frame.origin.y += 30
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        circles.forEach {
            $0.layer.cornerRadius = 20/2
            $0.layer.masksToBounds = true
            $0.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
            stackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
            $0.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
            $0.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: $0.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        animate()
    }
}
```

It should be pretty straightforward, but feel free to let me know if you have any questions!

**And this is how the result looks like:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using a `CAKeyframeAnimation` instead of handling completion blocks and that sorcery. Here's a quick example:

```
for i in 0 ..< 3 {
    let bubble = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 20 + i * 20, y: 200, width: 10, height: 10))
    bubble.backgroundColor = .red
    bubble.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    self.view.addSubview(bubble)

    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation()
    animation.keyPath = "position.y"
    animation.values = [0, 10, 0]
    animation.keyTimes = [0, 0.5, 1]
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
    animation.duration = 1
    animation.isAdditive = true
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE
    animation.timeOffset = CACurrentMediaTime() + 0.2 * Double(i)

    bubble.layer.add(animation, forKey: "anim")
}
```

When you wanna remove the animation you just use `bubble.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "anim")`. You might have to play around with the timing function or `values` and `keyTimes` to get the exact movement you want. But keyframes is the way to go to make a specific animation.

Side note: this example won't work in `viewDidLoad` cause the view doesn't have a superview yet so the animation won't work. If you test it in `viewDidAppear` it will work.

Answer (score 2):

UIView animation is different to CALayer animation,best not to mix them.
Write locally and tested.

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class HTAnimatedTypingView: UIView {

    private let view0 = UIView()
    private let view1 = UIView()
    private let view2 = UIView()

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        makeUI()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        makeUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        makeUI()
    }

    private func makeUI() {

        backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        view0.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        addSubview(view0)
        addSubview(view1)
        addSubview(view2)

        view0.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.centerY.equalTo(self.snp.centerY)
            make.width.equalTo(10)
            make.height.equalTo(10)
            make.left.equalTo(self.snp.left)
        }

        view1.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.centerY.equalTo(self.snp.centerY)
            make.width.equalTo(10)
            make.height.equalTo(10)
            make.centerX.equalTo(self.snp.centerX)
        }

        view2.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.centerY.equalTo(self.snp.centerY)
            make.width.equalTo(10)
            make.height.equalTo(10)
            make.right.equalTo(self.snp.right)
        }

    }

    public func startAnimation() {

        let duration:CFTimeInterval = 0.5
        let animation_delay:CFTimeInterval = 0.1

        assert(duration >= animation_delay * 5, "animation_delay should be way smaller than duration in order to make animation natural")

        let translateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")
        translateAnimation.duration = duration
        translateAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        translateAnimation.toValue = 0
        translateAnimation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.both
        translateAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        translateAnimation.autoreverses = true

        view0.layer.add(translateAnimation, forKey: "translation")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + animation_delay) { [unowned self ] in
            self.view1.layer.add(translateAnimation, forKey: "translation")
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + animation_delay * 2) { [unowned self ] in
            self.view2.layer.add(translateAnimation, forKey: "translation")
        }

    }

    public func stopAnimation() {
        self.view0.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.view1.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.view2.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private func animateDots(circles: [UIView]){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            circles[0].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.8, y: 1.8)
         }) { (finished) in
             UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                 circles[0].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
                 circles[1].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.8, y: 1.8)
              }) { (finished) in
                  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                      circles[1].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
                      circles[2].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.8, y: 1.8)
                   }) { (finished) in
                       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                           circles[1].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
                           circles[2].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.8, y: 1.8)
                        }) { (finished) in
                            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
                                circles[2].transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)
                             }) { (finished) in
                                 self.animateDots(circles: circles)
                            }
                       }
                  }
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Good answers explain how they solve the question's issue.

Comment: @HangarRash The code explains the logic itself, rather than creating ongoing 3 timers, it would be best to use recursive function. Here the series of animations are called post completion of one animation. If you find it difficult to comprehend, then I can give more explanation.

Comment: I can read and understand your code just fine. That's not the point. As I said, a good answer provides some explanation. A good answer addresses the issues in the question in addition to providing a possible code solution.